rsync keeps changing two directories
I am trying to synchronise a directory from a local ext4 filesystem to three FreeBSD ufs filesystems using rsync. Here is my setup:

Local machine running GNU/Linux, ext4 filesystem mounted at /mnt
Remote machine running FreeBSD 14.1 with three ufs filesystems mounted under /media/m1, /media/m2, /media/m3

I first sync from local to the first remote disk with:
sudo rsync -auv --delete -A -X --exclude=lost+found \
  --rsync-path='sudo /usr/local/bin/rsync' --numeric-ids \
  /mnt/ username@hostname:/media/m1/backup

Note that rsync is running with root privileges both on the local and on the remote machine. Also, on the FreeBSD machine the filesystems are mounted with the acls option:
sudo mount -o acls -t ufs ...

so the rsync option -A should work correctly.
After running rsync once (no errors reported), I ran it a second time and expected that no changes would be reported. However, during the second run, two folders were logged as if they had been changed again:
sending incremental file list
backup/folder/subfolder1/
backup/folder/subfolder2/

No matter how often I run the command, the two subfolders are always listed. It looks as if rsync tries to set some attributes on the folders but does not succeed.
Interestingly, when I try to synchronise the folders between the mounted ufs filesystems on the remote machine, e.g. with
sudo rsync -auv --delete -A -X --numeric-ids /media/m1/backup/ /media/m2/backup

I get the same behaviour: during the first run, all the files from the original folder are listed; during the subsequent runs, the same two directories are reported again and again:
sending incremental file list
backup/folder/subfolder1/
backup/folder/subfolder2/

It is as if rsync is trying to change something, fails without reporting an error, and tries over and over again. Bottom line: my backup copies are different from the original.
Do you have an explanation of this behaviour or some hints as to
what should I look at to solve this problem?
EDIT
Thanks to Kusalananda for the hint. I have run rsync again with the -i option. The changes are now displayed as follows:
sending incremental file list
.d.......a. backup/folder/subfolder1/
.d.......a. backup/folder/subfolder2/

where the d means that a directory is being synchronised, and a means that the ACL for that entry is being modified.
So I looked at the ACLs for both directories on the source and target system. On the source (GNU/Linux) machine I have:
$ sudo getfacl -n subfolder1
# file: subfolder1
# owner: 1001
# group: 1001
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

while on the target (FreeBSD) machine I have
$ sudo getfacl -n subfolder1
# file: subfolder1
# owner: username
# group: username
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

The only difference I can see is that the owner and group are resolved on the target system (1001 is user username and 1001 is group username) while on the source system there are no user or group 1001, so the numeric values are displayed.
Since I have the same problem between two disks on the FreeBSD system, I also ran:
sudo rsync -au -i --delete -A -X --numeric-ids /media/m1/backup/ /media/m2/backup

and got
sending incremental file list
.d.......a. backup/folder/subfolder1/
.d.......a. backup/folder/subfolder2/

Querying the ACLs on the m2 filesystem gives the same result:
$ sudo getfacl -n subfolder1
# file: subfolder1
# owner: username
# group: username
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

In case this is relevant, here are the rsync versions I am using:

GNU/Linux: rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
FreeBSD: rsync  version 3.3.0  protocol version 31


Run with -i (--itemize-changes) instead of with -v to see why something got updated.
